# Saving state of UIButton (checkbox) - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton, nsuserdefaults

I'm a new developer and I'm making a to-do list app in Swift. I was able to figure out how to change the state of the `UIButton` (checkbox) on clicking. At the moment I'm trying to figure out how to save that state for when I exit the app or switch views and return. I was able to successfully save the text (to-do list tasks) by using `NSUserDefaults` and have also experimented with it on my buttons but cannot figure out how to get it to work.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var myButton: Qbutton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var isChecked = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isBtnChecked") // here we obtain the last state of the button
    myButton.isChecked = isChecked
    self.view.addSubview(myButton)
```

I have the `UIButton` in a subclass of `QButton`.

```
class Qbutton: UIButton {

    var isSelected: Bool = defaults.boolForKey("isButtonChecked")

    // Images
    let selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Selected")
    let unselectedImage = UIImage(named: "Unselected")


    //Bool Property
    var isChecked:Bool = false{
        didSet{
            if isChecked == true{
                self.setImage(selectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }else{
                self.setImage(unselectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
            defaults.setObject(isChecked, forKey: "isButtonChecked")
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame:frame)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.setImage(unselectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.isChecked = false
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if(sender == self){
        if isChecked == true{
            isChecked = false
        }else{
            isChecked = true
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine, what are you having trouble with? Access your defaults by `var isSelected: Bool = defaults.boolForKey("SelectedState")`

Comment: if isChecked == true is redundant. if isChecked {...}

Comment: Also if you want to switch a Bool value(func checkBox) you could simply do like this:  isChecked = !isChecked

Comment: I went ahead and refactored some of my code. I'm still having an issue because when I close out of the app and try to run it, the state of my buttons will not save.

Answer (score 1):

well i think you can save the state of the `UIButton` with the `NSUserDefaults` just when the variable isChecked is changed. Something like this:

```
var isChecked:Bool = false{
    didSet{
        if isChecked {
            self.setImage(selectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }else{
            self.setImage(unselectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(isChecked, forKey: "isBtnChecked")
        // this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, but
        //if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization you can invoke it
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize() 
    }


}
```

Now when your app is launched you can check the last state of the `UIButton` with this:

```
var isSelected: Bool = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isBtnChecked")
```

UPDATE

I made an example using your `Qbutton` class. I hope this can help you:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Qbutton: UIButton {

    // Images
    let selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Selected")
    let unselectedImage = UIImage(named: "Unselected")

    //Bool Property
    var isChecked:Bool = false{
        didSet{
            if isChecked {
                self.setImage(selectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }else{
                self.setImage(unselectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(isChecked, forKey: "isBtnChecked")
            // this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, but
            //if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization you can invoke it
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame:frame)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.setImage(unselectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.isChecked = false
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        if(sender == self){
            if isChecked == true{
                isChecked = false
                self.setImage(unselectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }else{
                isChecked = true
                self.setImage(selectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the `UIViewController` i create a `Qbutton` and before i add it to the `UIViewController` view i read the last state of the variable "isBtnChecked".

From the [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html):

> If a boolean value is associated with defaultName in the user defaults, that value is returned. Otherwise, NO is returned.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var myButton: Qbutton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myButton = Qbutton(frame: CGRectMake(100,100,50 ,50));
        var isChecked = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isBtnChecked") // here we obtain the last state of the button
        myButton.isChecked = isChecked // we set the value
        self.view.addSubview(myButton)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
}
```

UPDATE 2

Here is an example using the selected property of `UIButton`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Qbutton: UIButton {

    // Images
    let selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Selected")
    let unselectedImage = UIImage(named: "Unselected")


    //Bool Property
    override var selected: Bool{
        didSet{
            if selected {
                self.setImage(selectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }else{
                self.setImage(unselectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(selected, forKey: "isBtnChecked")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame:frame)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.setImage(unselectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   }

    func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        self.selected = !self.selected
    }
}
```

And the `UIViewController` :

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var myButton: Qbutton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myButton = Qbutton(frame: CGRectMake(100,100,50 ,50));
        myButton.selected = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isBtnChecked") // here we obtain the last state of the button
        self.view.addSubview(myButton)

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
}
```

I hope this really can help you!

Comment: Yes, it's less redundant.

Comment: This solution half solves my problem. I'm unable to add the `NSUSerDefaults` outside of the second curly braces. Only the braces immediately following `else`. Also, where to I add the `var` instance?

Comment: When adding the `var` inside my Button class and adding the `NSUserDefaults` immediately after the `else` statement, upon selecting a button it only selects the top one in my table and also will not let me unselect it.

Comment: check my updated answer, i try to show you a full working code example

Comment: Why is there any need for the addition of isChecked when the `selected` property of a UIButton would work perfectly for this task?

Comment: Could you possibly show me this in code Chris? I'm looking for the most effective way to accomplish this task. Thank you.

Comment: I use isChecked variable to store the value as soon as it changes and because i thought John needed to use that method, but you're right, to accomplish this task he should use imageForState and change the UIControlState of the button he wants to make a checkbox

Comment: I went ahead and added the changes and I'm getting an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. I changed the code above..

Comment: Calling `synchronize` on defaults is unnecessary in nearly all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are completely over-thinking it and making it complicated. Since it's just a simple button the easiest way to do it is set a bool through an `IBAction`. Let me know if I'm missing something from your question though.

In Objective-C it would be something like this..

```
{
    BOOL _isStateEnabled;
}

-(IBAction)clickedButton: (id)sender {
    _isStateEnabled = !_isStateEnabled;
}
```

In Swift I'm not fluent but, something like this..

```
{
    let _isStateEnabled as boolean;
}

func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    _isStateEnabled = !_isStateEnabled;
}
```

Comment: I'll have to take a closer look at that and convert it to Swift. Currently, I have my checkboxes working, they're just not saving to NSUserDefaults. That's my issue right now.

Comment: @JohnJLilley should be as easy as creating a Boolean variable and setting it to be 'not' what it is currently when you tap the button. You can encode and decode the Boolean using NSArchive.